# returning a string with decremented versions of itself

Tags: python, string

i am trying to write a code that takes a string and adds itself to the begginning of it missing the final letter until the string runs out. I originally had it as a print, but need to change to return, but it causes an error with the "end=''" syntax

sample output: "hey" ---> "hhehey"

```
def explode(str):
    for i in range(0, len(str)):
        return(str[0:i + 1], end='')
```

Comment: why did you change it ?

Comment: because there are print functions outside the method to test it

Answer (score 2):

If you want the method to return a string, you need to concatenate then return

```
def explode(value):
    result = ""
    for i in range(len(value)):
        result += value[:i + 1]
    return result
```

You can inline it

```
def explode(value):
    return "".join(value[:i + 1] for i in range(len(value)))

print(explode("hey"))  # hhehey
```